# Phase front of a laser beam through an imperfect optical element

Tags: optics, interference, coherence

I'm not sure what to make of the following thought experiment: consider a [Rayleigh interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_interferometer), where one arm holds a cuvette with some transparent liquid. The aim is to measure the refractive index of the liquid by making the two beams interfere.

My question is whether the cuvette walls need to be optical perfect to within less than a wavelength across the size of the laser beam for the interference to work (and not average out to a blur). I would naively expect that if the glass wall thickness is inhomogeneous, different parts of the beam will undergo a different phase shift, and therefore the beam's phase shift upon transmission will be completely scrambled. And in practice, especially with a plastic cuvette and an expanded laser beam (~a few mm), I really doubt that one can expect a flat and parallel cuvette wall.

Assuming the experiment somehow still works, despite such inhomogeneities, would it make sense to involve some "self-healing" property of the laser beam as it propagates towards the screen? Would the propagation-enhanced spatial coherence help recover a meaningful interference pattern when superimposed with the beam from the unperturbed arm? Or does one really need optically perfect components?

I could not find much information on this seemingly trivial question, save for the usual mention of speckle patterns, but this has more to do with scattering than phase shifts as far as I can tell.

Comment: You do need the windows to be optically perfect as you do not want the path lengths to differer across a beam of light.  Microscope slides are good enogh for most purposes..

Comment: @Farcher thanks, that was my original thought, but then we tried it quickly and it seemed to work with just a standard slide, and I find it hard to believe that it'd be flat and parallel to better than a wavelength across a couple of mm area. On the other hand, a plastic cuvette definitely kills it, so...

Comment: I got circular fringes with this set up which shows just how precisely microscope slides are manufactured. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/360815/104696